# Pass List argument to rmarkdown file (.Rmd)

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am generating an HTML report using rmarkdown. I want to pass the list of the tables through `render` method but it's throwing me an error:

```
Error in UseMethod("as.html") : 
no applicable method for 'as.html' applied to an object of class "character"
```

Code Snippet:

````
---
params: 
  tables: !r
---
```{r results='asis', echo=FALSE}
for(i in as.list(params$tables)){
  cat("######", as.html(i), "\n")
}

```
````

Please suggest a way to resolve.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide a default for tables, e.g

```
tables: !r "whatever"
```

I could not find the requirement in the docs, but it looks like an empty string such as "" does not work.

Add a reference to htmltools

```
library(htmltools)
```

There is no function as.html, only HTML in htmltools or shiny:

```
HTML(i)
```

Comment: Its giving me error: In yaml::yaml.load(yaml, handlers = knit_params_handlers(evaluate = evaluate)) :
  an error occurred when handling type 'r'; using default handler

Comment: Yes. I saw that error too, but the html output was Ok. Maybe @yihui can comment.

Comment: I found a bug in my code. I was passing "character" object in the tables list and was converting into as.html(). I removed that and it worked. Thanks Dieter Menne for the help.